# How to Order By a column but array come first

Tags: postgresql, sorting, sql-order-by

(Sorry for my bad English)

I have an array of users ids as below:

```
[5, 9, 3, 22, 16]
```

*Obviously the values are dynamic.*

Now, I need to `SELECT` all users but users with above ids come first.

**What I've tried so far?**

This query gives me exact answer :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (5, 9, 3, 22, 16)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (5, 9, 3, 22, 16);
```

But is there any better way?

P.S:

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from users
order by id not in (5, 9, 3, 22, 16), id
```

As stated in [the documentation,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#sql-orderby) an expression used in the ORDER BY clause

> can be an arbitrary expression formed from input-column values.

In particular, you can use a Boolean expression, as values of this type are sortable. Note that `false < true`.

Comment: I think OP want the ids from the array first. so should be `ID IN( ...)`

Comment: nvm I see you get 0 or 1 and those `NOT` get last :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE statements on your ORDER BY, I'll give you an example:

```
select *
from users
order by 
CASE WHEN id=5 THEN 1
WHEN id=9 THEN 2
WHEN id=3 THEN 3
WHEN id=22 THEN 4
WHEN id=16 THEN 5 
END, id
```

With CASE you can tell postgres the "priority" or value you want for each id if you know them beforehand. After that I added "id" so the rest of the rows gets ordered properly.